# pdfcomment and polyglossia incompatibility?

Tags: polyglossia, pdfcomment

I would like to use the `pdfcomment` package to make some annotations to a pdf. It seems to conflict with `polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor,pdfcomment,polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Squiggly,color=green,author={somebody}]{Some \emph{more} text. \textgerman{Etwas Text}.}{some suggestion}
\end{document}
```

Gives me the following error:

```
! Argument of \\textgerman has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.7 ... \textgerman{Etwas Text}.}{some suggestion}
```

If I replace the `\textgerman` by `\emph` the file builds fine.

Comment: Use `\protect\textgerman{Etwas Text}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that will make it compile again, but then the squiggly underline disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register `\textgerman` with `soul`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor,polyglossia}
\usepackage[draft]{pdfcomment}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\AtBeginDocument{\soulregister{\textgerman}{1}}

\begin{document}

Some text.
\pdfmarkupcomment[
  markup=Squiggly,
  color=green,
  author={somebody}
]{Some \emph{more} text. \textgerman{Etwas Text}.}{some suggestion}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That solves it for this problem, but now I ran into a similar problem with biblatex's `\cite` etc. commands, it seems they cannot be dealt with in the same way.

Comment: Here prefixing the `\cite` command with `\protect` works.

Comment: @muk.li `soul` is quite fragile; sometimes `\mbox{}` around an offending entry helps.